# digit_sum error, iterating through a string and then changing to an integer, python

Tags: python

On Codecademy.com I am on section 8, "Practice Makes Perfect", exercise 4 they ask you to:

> Write a function called **digit_sum** that takes a positive integer **n**
>   as input and returns the sum of all that number's digits. For example:
>   **digit_sum(1234)** should return **10** which is **1 + 2 + 3 + 4**. (Assume that
>   the number you are given will always be positive.)

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    n = str(n)
    for i in n:
        total += int(n[i])
    return total
```

Since you have to only add one of the digits, I wrote a program that changed the number into a string and then iterate over each digit. When I iterate, I add each number to a local varible, **total**, by accessing the digit and then changing the number back into an integer. After writing my program, I was thrown the error "*string indices must be integers, not str*". This is the error you get when you try to add a number to a string. I was confused by this so I researched if other people were having the same problem. I also asked my programming teacher and we still could not figure it out. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

It does not tell me what line is throwing the error either. I forgot to mention but on the website they give a solution, but it is not at all in the terms of what I am doing, I am just severely confused of why this error is occurring.

Comment: `for i in n:
        total += int(i)`

variable i is't index, i is value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
   def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    n = str(n)
    for i in n:
        total += int(i)
    return total
```

In python, unike c++ and other languages:
 the for loop iterates the element   itself and not its index.

Comment: Ok, I see now that since it loops through a string and not a list, that I don't need the indexes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates over the characters of your string, not the indices.  Change to:

```
def digit_sum2(n):
     total = 0
     n = str(n)
     for i in range(0, len(n)):
         total += int(n[i])
     return total
```

Comment: This one words as well. I now understand now that if you include the variable inside the for loop declaration, that you don't need to use the index. Thank you!

Comment: @Cade B.  Let's be a little more precise.  In your code `n` is modified from the number itself to a string representation of the number.  You then use `for i in n:`.  When `n` is a string, this means that `i` will iterate over the characters in the string.  So `i` is a character.  @Elizabeth's answer works because `int(i)` returns the integer representation of that character.   In my answer `for i in range(0, len(n))` iterates over the range [0, length of string n).  For a string of length K, `i` will take the values `0` to `K-1`.  Then `n[i]` is the character at position `i` of the string.